# Sony Smartwatch compatibility with regular headsets

Tags: compatibility, headset, sony-smartwatch

I bought a [Sony Smartwatch](http://www.sonymobile.com/gb/products/accessories/smartwatch/) and I wonder if it can be used with any bluetooth headset to take the calls. I know there is a [Smart Wireless Headset pro](http://www.sonymobile.com/gb/products/accessories/smart-wireless-headset-pro/) but it costs almost as much as the watch. Can I use the smartwatch with a regular bluetooth headset like [Samsung HM1200](http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/consumer/mobile/mobile-phones/accessories/BHM1200UBEGWDT?subsubtype=bluetooth-headset)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official Sony answer for my question (I didn't alter it):

> In regard to your question about if the smartwatch that you purchased
>   if can be use with any regular blueatooth headset and im going to use
>   the same example that you put the Samsung bluetooth headset, it might
>   be compatible but is not warranty that is going to work with every
>   single fuction of it do to the fact that the smartwatch is build to
>   work with sony devices.